# Change direction of css width transition

Tags: wordpress, css, css-transitions

I have a WordPress page with the twentythirteen theme. E.g.: https://twentythirteendemo.wordpress.com/

The last element of the navigation bar is the search form. If I click on the search form, a CSS transition is initiated which fades to the left, finally showing the whole search form.

I would like to place the magnifier-icon more on the left (this is easy: just changing the `right` css-property) and change the direction of the transition. The transition should go from left to right (not from right to left as is now).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the label on `position: absolute; left: 0;` the input will open to the right.

*edit*:

positioning an element to the right sets the alignment of the element to the right side. as `text-align` works on inlined elements, `right` and `left` works on absolute-positioned elements.

so, if you want to achieve a growth to the right, align the element to the left.

Comment: Please also explain WHY this works, so the OP can learn more instead of just copying answers :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the `right` property in the following CSS to `left`:

```
.site-header .search-form {
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Then the transition will be from left-to-right. Of course, the `px` need to be adapted accordingly.